# zsh stopped loading modules after I've run `autoload --help`

Tags: zsh

I have zsh installed with brew.

my `.zshrc`:

```
# installed packages
source $(brew --prefix)/opt/zsh-git-prompt/zshrc.sh
PROMPT='%B%m%~%b$(git_super_status) %# '

source $(brew --prefix)/share/zsh-syntax-highlighting/zsh-syntax-highlighting.zsh

. $(brew --prefix)/etc/profile.d/z.sh
```

I've tried fo figure out how to plug in automplition feature in to zsh. After I've run `autoload --help`, `zsh-git-prompt` stopped working.

If i run `source ~/.zshrc` i get this:

```
/Users/kulikalov/.zshrc:source:2: no such file or directory: /usr/local/opt/zsh-git-prompt/zshrc.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

> If i run `source ~/.zshrc` i get this:

You should never need to `source ~/.zshrc` manually. `.zshrc` gets sourced automatically whenever you start Zsh.

> ```bsh
> /Users/kulikalov/.zshrc:source:2: no such file or directory: /usr/local/opt/zsh-git-prompt/zshrc.sh
> ```

That means that you have not yet installed `zsh-git-prompt` with `brew`. If you want to do that, you should run `brew install zsh-git-prompt`.

However, https://github.com/olivierverdier/zsh-git-prompt has not been updated in 4 years. I would highly recommend using https://github.com/romkatv/powerlevel10k instead.

> After I've run `autoload --help`, `zsh-git-prompt` stopped working.

I don't know what you're trying to do here, but that probably doesn't do what you think it does. For more info on `autoload`, read

- http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Functions.html#Autoloading-Functions and
- http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html